# R: Vertex attributes do not match vertex names in an arc plot

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I wish to create a networked arc plot.  My issue is that the arcs are correct, as is the order of nodes.  However, the size of nodes (degrees) and fill and border colours (vfill, vborder) do not match the vertices' attributes.

My .gml file can be downloaded at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42761499/myarc.gml

Code:

```
library(igraph)
library(arcdiagram)
dat.g2 = read.graph("myarc.gml", format = "gml")
vlabels<-get.vertex.attribute(dat.g2, "name")
vfill<-get.vertex.attribute(dat.g2, "vfill")
vborder<-get.vertex.attribute(dat.g2, "vborder")
vgroups<-get.vertex.attribute(dat.g2, "group")
degrees<-get.vertex.attribute(dat.g2,"degree")
edgelist<-get.edgelist(dat.g2)
values<-as.numeric(get.edge.attribute(dat.g2, "value"))
par(mai=c(2.25,.25,.25,.25))
arc.p<-arcplot(edgelist, cex.labels = 0.8,
           ordering = vlabels,
           show.nodes = TRUE, 
           col.nodes = vborder, 
           bg.nodes = vfill, 
           cex.nodes = sqrt(degrees)/20,
           pch.nodes = 21, 
           lwd.nodes = 2, 
           line = 0.3,
           col.arcs = hsv(0, 0, 0.1, 0.4), 
           lwd.arcs = sqrt(values)/2,
           horizontal=TRUE,
           axes=FALSE)
```

In the plot the colours and node sizes are sometimes wrong. "Other Complaint" should be purple and CHPAIN yellow.  The sizes of at least CHPAIN and CARDOTH are wrong (CHPAIN is larger than CARDOTH, see myarc.gml).  I think the issue is because in the edge list the name of each node first appears in a slightly different order than the vertex order.
By edge list order I mean the first unique appearance of a node name when one looks across the row then down the column. i.e.the first 5 rows of the edge list reads:

- from               to
- 1 Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF  AF
- 2 Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF  Syncope
- 3 Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF  SOB
- 4 Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF  CHPAIN
- 5 Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF  CARDOTH

so the edge list order is "Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF" , "AF", "Syncope", "SOB", "CHPAIN", "CARDOTH"...
The vertex order is "Chest Pain, MI, CA, VF" , "AF", "Syncope", "SOB", "Other complaint", "CHPAIN"...

How can I get the vertex attributes (vfill, vborder, degrees) to match up with the vertex names on the graph?

Comment: The `arcdiagram` package is here: https://github.com/gastonstat/arcdiagram In case somebody wondered....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to also explicitly set the `vertices=` parameter. This is how the function knows what values to keep each of the `*.nodes` properties assigned to. You can use this in place of the `ordering=` parameter you have set now since you are not re-ordering the nodes at all.

```
arc.p<-arcplot(edgelist, vlabels, cex.labels = 0.8,
    show.nodes = TRUE, 
    col.nodes = vborder, 
    bg.nodes = vfill, 
    cex.nodes = sqrt(degrees)/20,
    pch.nodes = 21, 
    lwd.nodes = 2, 
    line = 0.3,
    col.arcs = hsv(0, 0, 0.1, 0.4), 
    lwd.arcs = sqrt(values)/2,
    horizontal=TRUE,
    axes=FALSE)
```

[image]